# HibernateProperties not considered in creating LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean manually

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to setup multiple databases in an existing spring boot application.

So, I've created a configuration bean like this for each database:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example.user.data")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.user.data.dao",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "userEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "userTransactionManager")
public class UserDataConfig {

    @Bean(name = "userDataSourceProps")
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.user.datasource")
    DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "userDataSource")
    DataSource dataSource() {
        return dataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "userEntityManagerFactory")
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder entityManagerFactoryBuilder) {
        return entityManagerFactoryBuilder
                .dataSource(dataSource())
                .packages("com.example.user.data.dao.entity")
                .persistenceUnit("users")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "userTransactionManager")
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("userEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }

}
```

And disabled these auto-configurations:

- DataSourceAutoConfiguration
- DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration

Everything works fine, but the jpa/hibernate properties does not applied;

For example i have entities which follows naming convention : `SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy` (which should be used by default); After these changes, the naming convention does not work, even if i define the property:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
```

I've debugged `EntityManagerFactoryBuilder` creation, its `jpaProperties` field is empty!

Have i missed something? or I should pass jpa-properties and/or hibernate-properties manually in creating `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`? For example:

```
return entityManagerFactoryBuilder
        .dataSource(dataSource())
        .properties(jpaAndHibernateProperties())
        .packages("com.example.user.data.dao.entity")
        .persistenceUnit("users")
        .build();
```

**UPDATE:**

After testing, I realized that only HibernateProperties (`spring.jpa.hibernate` path) does not applied. But JpaProperties (`spring.jpa` path) applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration#entityManagerFactory`, we need to create vendor-properties and pass it to EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.properties:

```
return entityManagerFactoryBuilder
        .dataSource(dataSource())
        .properties(vendorProperties())
        .packages("com.example.user.data.dao.entity")
        .persistenceUnit(persistenceUnit)
        .build();

protected Map<String, Object> vendorProperties() {
    return new LinkedHashMap<>(this.hibernateProperties
            .determineHibernateProperties(jpaProperties.getProperties(),
                    new HibernateSettings()
                            .ddlAuto(() -> "none")
                            .hibernatePropertiesCustomizers(new ArrayList<>()))
    );
}
```